Rag based comparison of 2 documents
I have prepared code for comparison of 2 documents, but it is answering apart from the documents information as well. I don't want that. How can I achieve this part?
I don't want to https://blog.langchain.dev/improving-document-retrieval-with-contextual-compression/.
I tried using this.
